# Gateaux derivative, expected value

Tags: statistics, derivatives

Suppose F,G be the distribution functions and

\begin{eqnarray*}
T(F) & = & \int xdF=E_{F}(x),\\
T(G) & = & \int xdG=E_{G}(x),\\
F_{t} & = & (1-t)F+tG,
\end{eqnarray*}

How to determine the Gateaux derivative of the expected value

\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(t) & = & \int xdF_{T},\\
 & = & \int xd((1-t)F+tG).
\end{eqnarray*}

I tried to use the following substitution

$$dF_{t}=\left(-F+G\right)dt,$$

and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(t) & = & \int xdF_{T},\\
 & = & \int\left(G-F\right)dt,\\
 & = & \int xGdt-\int xFdt,\\
 & = & t(E_{G}(x)-E_{F}(x)),
\end{eqnarray*}

which lead to

$$\varphi^{\prime}(t)=E_{G}(x)-E_{F}(x).$$

However, I am not sure if it is correct... Could anybody help me?

---

**P.S.**

I found another solution

\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(t) & = & \int xdF_{T},\\
 & = & \int xd\left((1-t)F+tG\right),
\end{eqnarray*}

and I am not sure, if this step is correct

\begin{eqnarray*}
\varphi(t) & = & \int xd\left((1-t)F\right)+\int xd\left(tG\right),\\
 & = & (1-t)\int xdF+t\int xdG,\\
 & = & (1-t)E_{F}(x)+tE_{Q}(x).
\end{eqnarray*}

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Are you missing density functions in your integrals? And are you integrating w.r.t. the right variables? E.g., shouldn't it be something like $\int xF\;dx = E_F(X)$ for your first equation? Plus when you said F, G are distribution functions did you really mean density functions?

Comment: You should treat $t$ as a constant. So $d((1-t) F + tG)= d((1-t)F) + d(tG) = (1-t)dF + t dG$.

Comment: @ Braindead: Thanks for the explanation...